# Send files using XmlHttpRequest and receiving in express/multer

Tags: javascript, file, express, xmlhttprequest, multer

i have the following code:

Client side:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('img-edit');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
console.log(file)
var formElement = document.getElementById("edit-team-form")
var formData = new FormData(formElement)
formData.append('sphoto', file);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3030/edit-team?id=57");
request.send(formData);
```

Server side:

```
app.post("/edit-team?:id", urlencodedParser , upload.single("sphoto"), (req, res) => {
 var editedTeam = req.body
 console.log(req.files)
 console.log(editedTeam)
})
```

What im trying to do is send a photo file and recieve it in my express app.

When i do a `console.log` of `var file` i get the info. But also i get an `500 (Internal Server Error)` in the post request.

Also, in my app console i get the following error:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\juanc\DesktopCrud-intento2\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juanc\Desktop\Crud-intento2\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
```

EDIT:

```
const multer = require ("multer")
const upload = multer({dest: './uploads/imagenes'})
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
```

In the folder where i storage the files, some files are created

Comment: Is it the correct file that has been created?

Comment: Yes, but i already fixed this generating a URL for the file, sending this and i modified my backend

Comment: So it's all good?

Comment: yeah, thanks for asking